# Rendering to a texture via FBO

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, opengl

I am trying to apply post processing effects to a small test program for OS X. I am trying to render the image into a texture and then render the texture to the screen (i haven't even gotten to writing a second shader for the final image). My code still just renders a black screen.

Here is the code to create the FBO. It is executed once at the beginning.

```
-(void)setupFramebuffer{
    [self setOpenGLContext:self.openGLContext];

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    CGSize textureSize = CGSizeMake(1024, 1024);

    glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, &textureFramebuffer);
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, textureFramebuffer);

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    textureImage = MFGLImageCreateWithImageID(texture, textureSize);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, textureSize.width, textureSize.height, 0,
                 GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT,
                           GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);

    if(glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_EXT)
        NSLog(@"Failed to create FBO: %i", glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT));

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    g_CurrentlyBoundTexture = 0;
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}
```

Here is the rendering code.

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    glUniform4f(g_OffsetUniform, dirtyRect.size.width/2.0, dirtyRect.size.height/2.0, 1, 1);
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, textureFramebuffer);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    [batchRenderer addFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, textureImage.size.width, textureImage.size.height) withAlpha:1 forImage:textureImage renderAlpha:YES offset:0 color:[NSColor redColor] renderMode:GL_TRIANGLES];
    [batchRenderer finishAndDrawBatch];
    glFlush();
}
```

Right now i am just clearing the FBO buffer and writing a red color to it. Then i pass the image to my batch renderer for rendering, however i still get nothing but a black screen. (The batch renderer is not the issue, the exact same code is used in other programs) Furthermore, when i comment out the code that binds the FBO in the draw method it draws the red without an issue.

Comment: There's a very large amount of code missing here.  Where is your code which creates the VBO that your texture is rendered to? That's the piece of code i'd be most interested in seeing.  Did you confirm that it works for other textures, not just your FBO texture?  Is there any way you can upload some more code to pastebin or github?